"unsupported base contract" on polygon
I created a safe on polygon a long ago matic:0x7A4207f8aa017763771A38b3Ee10D2b5f85e9A7A ,
Now i want to transfer funds but i got error "unsupported base contract" And asking to use CLI.
I am not a advance user to run commands. Help me to recover my funds.

you can find detailed instructions in this answer: ETH address under OP Network
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
